# Boost weak_ptr's in a multi-threaded program to implement a resource pool

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, smart-pointers

I'm thinking of using boost::weak_ptr to implement a pool of objects such that they will get reaped when nobody is using one of the objects.  My concern, though, is that it's a multi-threaded environment, and it seems there's a race condition between the last shared_ptr to an object going out of scope and a new shared_ptr being constructed from the weak_ptr.  Normally, you'd protect such operations with lock or something; however, the whole point here is that you don't know when the shared_ptr might be going out of scope.

Am I misunderstanding something about boost::shared_ptr and boost::weak_ptr?  If not, does anybody have any good suggestions on what to do?

Thanks.

Andrew

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To use a `weak_ptr`, you normally have to grab a strong reference by constructing a `shared_ptr` with it. This last step is atomic: you either get a strong reference back, or you get a `bad_weak_ptr` exception thrown. (Alternatively, call `lock()` on the `weak_ptr`, and either get a strong reference or null.)

Example (with `lock()`; easy enough to adapt to the other style):

```
void do_something(weak_ptr<foo> weak) {
    // Grab strong reference
    shared_ptr<foo> strong(weak.lock());
    if (strong) {
        // We now have a strong reference to use
    } else {
        // No strong references left; object already freed
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe there's no need to test whether your shared_ptr is valid or not, because the constructor will throw bad_weak_ptr exceptions if your week_ptr points to the deleted object. Or you should use weak_ptr<T>::lock() which doesn't throw but can return a shared_ptr which points to NULL.

Comment: So it's atomic?  The Thread Safety section in the man page leaves some doubt in my mind.

Comment: @Serge: Thank you! I'm going to fix my post.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young, would mind having a look at my post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9948113/boostweak-ptrt-lock-crashes-with-a-sigsegv-segmentation-fault ? My `weak_ptr<T>.lock()` method itself crashed.

Answer (score 3):

Both `boost::weak_ptr` and `boost::shared_ptr` are similar if it comes to thread safety: they are not thread safe if there is a risk that object is going to be destroyed somewhere. If your object referenced in `boost::shared_ptr` or weak_ptr is being referenced permanently somewhere, then use can use `shared/weak` ptrs without any risk.

But if some operation is going to dereference the last living instance of object, then at that time you cannot do some operations on `weak_ptr`: in particular: you cannot assign `weak_ptr` to another `weak_ptr` because it uses `shared_ptr` internally. Also, you cannot use lock because the result is undefined. Also, `expired()` method is useless to: it may return true, but then next line of your code, your object might be already expired.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, ish. In terms of accessing the pointers, Boost should have made everything safe; that's part of their point.

However, if you're expecting to have a delay between when the last shared_ptr goes out, and when you want to make the next one, you'll get a null pointer. (If you're checking appropriately, you should then have an appropro fail case).

But you can't end up with an invalid shared_ptr