# Thread-safe lazy get and release

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, lazy-evaluation

I'm running into kindof an annoying problem and would need some advice...

Let's say I have a bunch of small MyObject's, that can construct bigger MyExtendedObject's. MyExtendedObject's are big and CPU consuming so construction is lazy, and I try do remove them from memory as soon as possible:

```
MyExtendedObject * MyObject::GetExtentedObject(){
  if(NULL == ext_obj_){
    ext_obj_ = new MyExtendedObject;
  }
  ++ref_;
  return ext_obj_;
}
void MyObject::ReleaseExtentedObject(){
  if(0 == (--ref_))
  {
    if(NULL != ext_obj_)
    {
      delete ext_obj_;
      ext_obj_ = NULL;
    }
  }
}
```

Extended objects are only constructed once at the beginning and are destroyed when the last caller releases them. Note that some may be constructed more than once but this is not an issue here.

Now, this is absolutely not thread-safe so I did a "naive" thread-safe implementation:

```
MyExtendedObject * MyObject::GetExtentedObject(){
  Lock();
  if(NULL == ext_obj_){
    ext_obj_ = new MyExtendedObject;
  }
  ++ref_;
  Unlock();
  return ext_obj_;
}
void MyObject::ReleaseExtentedObject(){
  Lock();
  if(0 == (--ref_))
  {
    if(NULL != ext_obj_)
    {
      delete ext_obj_;
      ext_obj_ = NULL;
    }
  }
  Unlock();
}
```

This is better but now I spend some non neglectable amount of time locking and unlocking...

I had the feeling we could pay the lock/unlock only when constructing or destructing.

I came up with this solution:

```
MyExtendedObject * MyObject::GetExtentedObject(){
  long addref = InterlockedCompareExchange(&ref_, 0, 0);
  long result;
  do{
    result = addref + 2;
  } while ((result-2) != (addref = InterlockedCompareExchange(&ref_, result, addref)));
  if(0 == (result&1)){
    Lock();
    if(NULL == ext_obj_){
      ext_obj_ = new MyExtendedObject;
      InterlockedIncrement(&ref_);
    }
    Unlock();
  }
  return ext_obj_;
}
void MyObject::ReleaseExtentedObject(){
  long release = InterlockedCompareExchange(&ref_, 0, 0);
  long result = 0;
  do{
    result = release - 2;
  } while ((result+2) != (release = InterlockedCompareExchange(&ref_, result, release)));
  if(1 == result)
  {
    Lock();
    if(1 == InterlockedCompareExchange((long*)&ref_, 0, 1))
    {
      if(NULL != ext_obj_)
      {
        delete ext_obj_;
        ext_obj_ = NULL;
      }
    }
    Unlock();
  }
}
```

Some explanations:

- I cannot use Boost. I'd like to but really cannot.
- I use only CompareExchange and Incr / Decr on purpose. Don't ask.
- I use first bit of ref_ to store the construction status (constructed / not constructed) and other bits for ref counting. It's the only way I found to manage 2 variables (ref counting and construction status) at the same time through atomic operations.

Some questions now :

- Do you think it's 100% bullet proof?
- Do you know some better solutions?

EDIT: Some have proposed to use shared_ptr. One up for a working solution with shared_ptr! Note that I need: lazy construction AND destruction when nobody no more use it.

Comment: There's no need to spell `Extended` as either `Extented` or `Extanted`, let alone both in the same program.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to correct it. English is not my native language :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Steve said, you basically want shared_ptr for the construction/destruction part. If you can't use boost, then I'd recommend copying the appropriate code from the boost headers (I believe the license allows this), or whatever other workaround you need to circumvent your dumb corporate policies. The other advantage of this approach is that when you can adopt TR1 or C++0x, you won't need do rewrite/maintain any custom implementation, you can just use the [then] built-in library code.

As for the thread safety (which Steve didn't address), I find it's almost always a good idea to use synchronization primitives rather than trying to get it right yourself with custom locking. I'd suggest using a CRITICAL_SECTION, and then adding some timing code to make sure the total lock/unlock time is negligible. Doing a lot of lock/unlock operations is fine, as long as there's not too much contention, and you won't have to debug obscure threaded access issues.

That's my advice, anyway, FWIW.

Edit: I should add that once you're effectively using boost, you'll probably want to keep a weak_ptr in the MyObject class, so you can check if the extended object still exists on the "get" function without holding a reference to it. This will allow your "ref counted destruction" when no external caller is still using the instance. So, your "get" function looks like:

```
shared_ptr< MyExtendedObject > MyObject::GetExtentedObject(){
  RIIALock lock( my_CCriticalSection_instance );
  shared_ptr< MyExtendedObject > spObject = my_weak_ptr.lock();
  if (spObject) { return spObject; }

  shared_ptr< MyExtendedObject > spObject = make_shared< MyExtendedObject >();
  my_weak_ptr = spObject;
  return spObject;
}
```

... and you don't need a release function, cause that part is done automatically through shared_ptr's reference counting. Hope that's clear.

See: [Boost weak_ptr's in a multi-threaded program to implement a resource pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160334/boost-weak-ptrs-in-a-multi-threaded-program-to-implement-a-resource-pool) for more info on weak_ptr and threading safety.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But as I said I'm still waiting for a solution with shared_ptr that totally meets my needs. And for your information my lock unlock mechanism is implemented through critical sections.

Comment: Ok so for your EDIT, it should work and I had in the early stages a solution that was close to this: You still have a full lock for each GetExtentedObject call. My final intend was to fully get rid of locks when just the ref count is updated.

Comment: I'd want to see this proven with timing output/etc. before I didn't use it. You're free to try to optimize it further and/or try to roll your own lock-free style implementation (which, as I said, I would not recommend), but if your locking time is non-negligible compared to your object initialization and other operations, perhaps you have other design problems.

Comment: @Nick: building `shared_ptr` with the `make_shared` function yields more compact pointers, increasing speed and improving memory usage. Nearly forgot: that's the best solution I could think of too, especially with the `weak_ptr` bit.

Comment: @Nick - I learnt that when you can avoid locks, you should. Maybe it would not be significantly better to avoid locking when you're just updating ref count, but I just would find it more elegant :)

Comment: @Nick - just one last question: Is the line "shared_ptr< MyExtendedObject > spObject = my_weak_ptr.lock();" totally thread safe? Can't we have a thread deleting the extending object between the call to lock and the actual affectation?

Comment: Per boost docs, I believe it should be thread safe; the point is that if/once the resulting shared_ptr is valid, you have increased the reference count. Of course, you'd need to copy the boost source to ensure your implementation was equally safe.

Comment: @Matthieu - I added your suggestion; this is indeed slightly more efficient. I'm not totally sure all my syntax is correct, but the idea should be obvious enough. @Julio, re: locks - As I said, I would not recommend trying to creatively avoid locking while writing stuff you know is going to be MT-accessible: it's hard and error prone, and doesn't save you much perf-wise. YMMV, but I wouldn't advise it.

Comment: Thanks. I voted for your answer even though my question "Is my own implementation valid?" still remains ;)

Comment: @Julio: the call to `lock` is thread-safe. Either it successfully increase the reference count before the object is destroyed (and returns a pointer to the object) or it doesn't and return null. You just need to test that the resulting `shared_ptr` is not null.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are partway to reconstructing [boost::shared_ptr](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm), which offers reference counting of an object via an encapsulated raw pointer.

In your case usage would be `boost::shared_ptr<MyExtendedObject>`.

EDIT: Per @ronag's comment, `shared_ptr` is now supported natively by many current compilers after being accepted into the latest version of the language.

EDIT: First time construction:

```
shared_ptr<MyExtendedObject> master(new MyExtendedObject);
```

When the last copy of `master` goes out of scope, `delete MyExendedObject` will be called.

Comment: Yeah I suspected that. Let's say I can't use boost. I would like to but I really can't. You know, big companies, strange policies, etc...

Comment: @Julio - this part of Boost is header-only.  Download that header and reuse the code you need.

Comment: You have std::tr1::shared_ptr or std::shared_ptr as well.

Comment: Ok so let's say a shared_ptr won't give me any solution to my problem. How do I manage the "first time case" (construction) and the last one (destruction) through a shared_ptr ?

Comment: @Julio - see second EDIT. Use `shared_ptr` copies of the initial to reference the object - when the last `shared_ptr` goes out of scope, the underlying object gets deleted.