# Breaking a circular dependency between a shared_ptr and a unique_ptr

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, smart-pointers, unique-ptr, circular-dependency

Given this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class Controller;

class View {
public:
    ~View() {
        std::cout << "Disposing View" << std::endl;
    }

    void SetObserver(std::shared_ptr<Controller> a_observer) {
        observer = a_observer;
    }
private:
    std::shared_ptr<Controller> observer;
};

class Controller : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Controller> {
public:
    static std::shared_ptr<Controller> Create(std::unique_ptr<View> view) {
        //Can't use std::make_shared due to visibility rules :(
        auto controller = std::shared_ptr<Controller>(new Controller(std::move(view)));

        controller->Init();

        return controller;
    }

    ~Controller() {
        std::cout << "Disposing Controller" << std::endl;
    }
private:
    std::unique_ptr<View> view;

    explicit Controller(std::unique_ptr<View> a_view) : view(std::move(a_view)) {}

    Controller(const Controller&) = delete;

    void Init() {
        view->SetObserver(shared_from_this());
    }
};

int main() {
    auto view = std::make_unique<View>();

    auto controller = Controller::Create(std::move(view));

    return 0;
}
```

I think that the `controller` object will never be disposed (confirmed by [running it](http://ideone.com/fcgt33)).

In order to alleviate this issue, is it sufficient to make the `observer` variable a `weak_ptr`instead of a `shared_ptr`?

Besides this, is there any other potential issue that I should be aware of, given the above design?

Comment: *"Can't use std::make_shared due to visibility rules"* - See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8147027/how-do-i-call-stdmake-shared-on-a-class-with-only-protected-or-private-const

Comment: @ChristianHackl Thanks for linking that answer, but I think I'll stick to using `new` for now. I don't want to add too much clutter into the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, as you state about [`std::weak_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr):

> In addition, `std::weak_ptr` is used to break circular references of std::shared_ptr.

Changing the member to `std::weak_ptr` and running, yields

```
$ ./a.out 
Disposing Controller
Disposing View
```

When you need it, just call `lock` (checking the return value), to obtain a `std::shared_ptr` (which you should *not* store as a member):

```
void doSomethingWithView() {
    auto obs = observer.lock();                                                                                                                                                                          
    if(obs) {
        // Still valid
    }   
}
```

---

A possible caveat has to do with [`std::weak_ptr` and multithreading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20754370/about-race-condition-of-weak-ptr).

Answer (score 2):

Using a `std::weak_ptr` would be okay, but given that the lifetime of the `View` is tied to its `Controller`, you can just store a regular pointer to the `Controller`. This way, the `Controller` doesn't have to be stored in a `std::shared_ptr`, and you can get rid of the `std::enable_shared_from_this` two-stage initialization mess.

I would also make `SetObserver` private and make `Controller` a friend of `View` for safety reasons. They're already tightly coupled after all.

```
#include <memory>

class Controller;

class View {
  friend class Controller;

private:
    void SetObserver(Controller* a_observer) {
        observer = a_observer;
    }

private:
    Controller* observer = nullptr;
};

class Controller {
public:
    explicit Controller(std::unique_ptr<View> a_view) :
        view(std::move(a_view)) {
        view->SetObserver(this);
    }

private:
    std::unique_ptr<View> view;
};

int main() {
    Controller controller(std::make_unique<View>());
}
```

As a side note, you could use [`std::observer_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/observer_ptr) to signal your intent when it becomes part of the standard.

Comment: I didn't know about `std::observer_ptr`. Looks like a neat addition for future implementations. Thanks!