# Using std::weak_ptr with std::shared_ptr for shadowing

Tags: c++, c++11, thread-safety, shared-ptr, weak-ptr

The documentation for `std::weak_ptr` [on cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr/lock) says this

> Effectively returns `expired() ? shared_ptr<T>() : shared_ptr<T>(*this)`, executed atomically.

And my judgement and [other SO answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30085310/5501675) have confirmed that the following is not prone to races

```
int main() {
    auto s_ptr = std::make_shared<T>(...);
    auto w_ptr = std::weak_ptr<T>{s_ptr};

    auto one = std::thread{[&]() {
        auto ptr = w_ptr.lock();
        if (ptr) { ... }
    }};
    s_ptr = std::make_shared<T>(...);

    one.join();
}
```

However can this reliably be used to shadow computation in a program?  By shadowing I mean something like this

```
auto s_ptr = std::make_shared<T>(...);
auto w_ptr = std::weak_ptr<T>{s_ptr};

// thread one
while (...) {
    auto ptr = w_ptr.lock();
    cout << "Value contained is " << *ptr << endl;
}

// thread two
while (...) {
     // do the heavy computation on the side
     auto new_value = fetch_new_value();

     // then "atomically" swap
     s_ptr = std::make_shared<T>(std::move(new_value));
}
```

The confusing part here is what `.lock()` returns.  Can it return a `nullptr`?  All the documentation says is that the operation will be executed atomically.  Doesn't say what this mutual exclusion means.  Can there be a state in `shared_ptr::operator=` where the pointer is null?  And can the `weak_ptr` access this state?  The documentation for `shared_ptr::operator=` [on cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/operator%3D) does not seem to mention this.

Comment: I cannot cite chapter & verse, but I believe that shared_ptr and its little buddy weak_ptr are thread safe.  The `auto ptr = w_ptr.lock()` can indeed return `nullptr` if all of the shared_ptr's have been destructed.  In my opinion, shared_ptr and weak_ptr are two of the best features of C++11, even when not in a threaded scenario.

Comment: And you might want to use this idiomatic pattern:  `if (auto ptr = w_ptr.lock()) { cout << "Value contained is " << *ptr << endl; } else { cout << "Value is dead, Jim." << endl; }`

Comment: Yeah, I just realized these two can be nice substitutes for the `atomic_...` stuff for `shared_ptr`.  As long as the above is valid i.e. (.lock() doesn't  return `nullptr` as long as the `shared_ptr` it was referring to was valid)

Comment: @Eljay I didn't include that on purpose.  In the context of this question, if we assume the shared_ptr itself doesnt get destroyed, is that condition needed?  I guess that itself is the question I wanted to ask

Comment: :-)  Yes, if it is reliable that the share_ptr isn't destroyed, the weak_ptr will not return nullptr.  (But that may become a "future bug" if someone refactors the code.)

Comment: @Eljay if you could point me to a source (or put up a convincing argument that proves why the converse would be invalid) that confirms this in an answer I would accept it 

Comment: Hmmm, here's a more detailed answer. • https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14482830/stdshared-ptr-thread-safety •  The key point being that only the control block itself is thread-safe.

Comment: From what I can see as soon as your shared pointer gets a new value, your weak pointer will start returning `nullptr` (because the original object got destroyed). But there will be no undefined behavior (because the handoff is atomic)

Comment: @Galik uh, I should have tried this before asking https://wandbox.org/permlink/UEYf1kn3ivfmMnwY.  Anyway, I'll update the question

Comment: You need to get a new weak pointer every time your shared pointer gets reset.

Comment: @Galik but is that thread safe by itself?  I don't think so.  I assume thats why the `atomic_` methods are there

Comment: Anything that relates to the control bloc (the reference count) is atomic. So obtaining a new weak pointer is thread safe but not guaranteed to be pointing at anything. (if other threads have access to your shared pointer).

Comment: @Galik do you want to put that up as an answer? Along with a suggestion on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As soon as your shared pointer gets a new value, your weak pointer will start returning `nullptr` The reason being that the original object gets destroyed as soon as your shared pointer starts pointing to a different object.

But there will be no undefined behavior exchanging pointers because the handoff is atomic.

(Although, dereferencing the `nullptr` value shared pointer returned by `w_ptr.lock()` is undefined and will likely crash the program).

You would need to get a new weak pointer every time your shared pointer gets reset with a new value. But whether or not the shared pointer is still pointing at that new value by the time you `lock()` your weak pointer is anyone's guess.

Anything that relates to the control bloc (the reference count) is atomic. So obtaining a new weak pointer is thread safe but not guaranteed to be pointing at anything (if other threads have access to your shared pointer).

Comment: +1 on Galik's answer.  `s_ptr = make_shared<T>(move(new_value));` resulted in w_ptr becoming `nullptr`.  But instead `*s_ptr = new_value;` resulted in w_ptr seeing the change, however that's running with mutating scissors (as previously discussed) when multithreaded.  Need something additional to coordinate mutations across threads.

Answer (score 1):

This code can execute UB:

```
auto s_ptr = std::make_shared<T>(...);
auto w_ptr = std::weak_ptr<T>{s_ptr};

// thread one
while (...) { // A
  auto ptr = w_ptr.lock(); // B
  cout << "Value contained is " << *ptr << endl; // C
}

// thread two
while (...) {
  // do the heavy computation on the side
  auto new_value = fetch_new_value();

  // then "atomically" swap
  s_ptr = std::make_shared<T>(std::move(new_value)); // X
}
```

If thread two executed `// X` before thread one executed `// B`, `weak_ptr` no longer refers to any data.

`.lock()` then returns a "null" `shared_ptr`, which you proceed to dereference at `// C`.

If you guarded use of `ptr` against it being null, there would be no UB apparent.

Comment: Got it, I had originally misunderstood the relation between `shared_ptr` and `weak_ptr`.  The relation is not with the `shared_ptr` object but with the control block..  I've just never used `weak_ptr` before and thought I had a good usecase for it..