# std::shared_ptr concurrent access sanity check

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, shared-ptr

I'm trying to make sure I correctly understand the [semantics of `std::shared_ptr`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54171737/616460), where:

- Modifications to the underlying shared reference counter (`std::_Sp_counted_base` in the stdc++ implementation that ships with GCC) are thread-safe.
- Access to a *given instance* of an `std::shared_ptr` is not thread-safe.

With that in mind, consider the following snippet:

```
struct Data {
    std::shared_pointer<X> x;
    std::shared_pointer<Y> y;
};

void SomeThread1 (Data d) {
    std::shared_pointer<X> localxptr = d.x;
    ...
}

void SomeThread2 (std::shared_ptr<Data> d) {
    std::shared_pointer<X> localxptr = d.x;
    ...
}
```

Assuming `SomeThread[12]` are their own threads, and whoever created them passed the appropriate parameters, am I correct in believing that:

- `SomeThread1` is safe: Since `d` is a copied `Data`, `d.x` is therefore a unique instance of the `shared_ptr<X>` member and can thus be copied again safely into `localxptr`.
- `SomeThread2` is *not* safe: Since `d` is a pointer to a `Data`, `d.x` is therefore the same `shared_ptr<X>` instance that the calling thread has and thus cannot be copied safely into `localxptr`, which risks both the new thread and the calling thread (and anybody else) accessing that same `shared_ptr<X>` instance.

Is my assessment correct?

Seems obvious, but I just want a sanity check because I've been staring at a lot of code for too long lately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other question you linked seems to provide the answer: it depends on what other threads may be doing.

A `shared_ptr` is not thread safe **if it is used in a non-const way**. However, you are only passing it in to [the copy constructor (9)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr), which accepts it as a const reference. If all other threads are accessing it in the same way (none of them attempt to modify it), this is safe as written.

Comment: Thank you; that's all I needed to hear. I've gone ahead and confirmed the duplicate link.